# Transparent HTTPS Squid proxy with upstream parent

Tags: proxy, squid, https

I've got a network without direct internet access where I have **Squid 3.5.9** as a *transparent proxy* listening on `tcp/8080` for HTTP and on `tcp/8443` for HTTPS (redirected via `iptables` from tcp/80 and tcp/443 respectively).

This Squid doesn't have a direct Internet access either but can talk to a parent Squid in other part of the network that does have Internet access.

With HTTP it works well - client makes a request to http://www.example.com (port 80), router and iptables redirect the connection to Squid's port 8080, that intercepts the request and makes a request to the upstream proxy that serves it as usual. Here are the config options used:

```
http_port 8080 intercept
cache_peer proxy-upstream parent 3128 0 no-query
never_direct allow all
```

That works well. Now I wanted to do a similar thing for HTTPS:

```
https_port 8443 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/etc/squid/myCA.pem
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_children 5

ssl_bump bump all
```

Without `cache_peer` it works as expected, i.e. auto-generates a fake SSL cert and makes a direct connection to the target.

However with `cache_peer` it doesn't work. I get HTTP/503 error from the proxy:

```
1446684476.877  0 proxy-client TAG_NONE/200 0 CONNECT 198.51.100.10:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1446684476.970  3 proxy-client TCP_MISS/503 4309 GET https://secure.example.com/ - FIRSTUP_PARENT/proxy-upstream text/html
```

Alternatively if I change the `ssl_bump` setup to this:

```
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
```

I get a crash message in cache.log:

```
2015/11/05 01:07:11 kid1| assertion failed: PeerConnector.cc:116: "peer->use_ssl"
```

When I use this proxy in non-transparent mode, i.e. configuring the proxy on client to proxy-test:3128, it works:

```
1446684724.879 141 proxy-client TCP_TUNNEL/200 1886 CONNECT secure.example.com:443 - FIRSTUP_PARENT/proxy--upstream -
```

So I need to somehow turn the `HTTPS` request that lands on *proxy-test* into `CONNECT` request that's forwarded to *proxy-upstream*. If Squid can't do that is there any other transparent-to-nontransparent proxy software that can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `sslproxy_cert_error allow all` and `sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER`.  BTW if it is at all possible having the clients configured to use the proxy is always better than transparent proxying - maybe redirect transproxied https (and maybe http too) requests to a page that gives instructions on how to setup the proxy for several common browsers.

Comment: Finding a question that is _exactly_ what I'm trying to do - great! Discovering it has no answers - not great :( @MLu do you remember if/how you ever solved this?

Comment: @stripybadger if I remember correctly in the end we simply used non-transparent proxy. We’ve had too much trouble with the transparent one, with invalid / fake certs, etc.